# Check Textbox on webpage for specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to have a empty textbox and if someone enters in a specific text and hits the submit button it redirect them to another site, if the text is anything else is redirects to a different website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use this code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" />
<button type="submit" onclick="buttonClicked()"></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputText".value == "YourText")) {
        window.location.href = "yourfile.html";
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "otherfile.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help. Please can you accept my answer if it worked?

Comment: actually having a problem now any clue why this isn't working <script>
function buttonClicked() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputText".value == "YourText") {
        window.location.href = "yourfile.html";
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "otherfile.html";

    }
}
</script>





<input type="text" id="inputText" />
<button type="submit" onclick="buttonClicked()"></button>

Comment: You need to name your files correctly, the ones I put in were just examples.

Comment: when I click the button it does nothing

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` statement inside the function and seeing if it runs correctly.

Comment: yeah i know it doesn't even attempt to redirect the page though

Comment: figured it out your "YourText") needed another )